# encryption algorithm rijnadael C# on Delphi

Tags: delphi

Did not get to move rijnadael encryption algorithm with C # on delphi.

```
Rijndael aes;
byte[] retVal = null;
byte[] contentBytes;
byte[] passwordBytes;
byte[] ivBytes;

string content = "3wAHQZwW7y115QvI0PuSltzBgNmhPvkk0Cw1zKUTX9kEs18rnwKzXBIadf4vTMyCFGolYRpu9vlwyUHuGfMe7eAhULgEBjb9Yoawl3dgYQo=";
string password="GAT";

    contentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
    passwordBytes = new byte[32];
    ivBytes = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password), passwordBytes, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password).Length);
    Array.Copy(passwordBytes, ivBytes, 16);
    using (aes = Rijndael.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = passwordBytes;
        aes.IV = ivBytes;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        retVal = aes.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
    }
```

DCP components used on Delphi, no particular success was not achieved.
Delphi XE5:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  din, dout: AnsiString;
  Vector: array of byte;
  Cipher : TDCP_rijndael;
  aKey:AnsiString;
begin
    SetLength(Vector, 16);

    aKey:='GAT';
    din:='3wAHQZwW7y115QvI0PuSltzBgNmhPvkk0Cw1zKUTX9kEs18rnwKzXBIadf4vTMyCFGolYRpu9vlwyUHuGfMe7eAhULgEBjb9Yoawl3dgYQo=';
    Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
    try
      Cipher.Init(aKey, Length(aKey)*8, Vector);
      Cipher.CipherMode := cmCBC;
      dout := Cipher.DecryptString(din);
    finally
      Cipher.Burn;
      Cipher.Free;
    end;
    showmessage(dout);
end;
```

that assign a vector?

Comment: Beyond the Delphi code, how about complete test programs, that can be run, for both languages that show the problem?

Comment: So, what do you expect this code to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: I do wonder what made you use strings to hold binary data. Strings are for text. This is the single most common mistake I see here. And it seems overwhelmingly common in the Delphi tag.

Comment: There is no suprise for this failure: The C# code seems to work with a 256 bit key (32 bytes), an IV with the first 16 bytes of the key, PKCS#7 padding but no (obvious) CBC mode. Your Delphi does not even mention 256 bit keys (you use 3*8=24 bits??), no padding, no IV, but it wants the CBC mode (and no reconversion from Base64).

Answer (score 0):

I think the Init and DecryptString methods use arrays as parameters but you are using strings, which are also basically also arrays in Delphi, but special ones. You have to point at the correct first item which is 1 unlike 0 in C.
You can of course first also transform your AnsiStrings in array of bytes and feed that to the methods.

```
.Init(aKey[1], ....)
```

and

```
.Decrypt(din[1])
```

hth